# eigen in groovy for ubuntu 12.04 armhf

Tags: eigen, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, armhf, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm installing ROS packages on Ubuntu Armhf, and although so far everything went fine, I find a difference with electric. According to http://answers.ros.org/question/10940/eigen-in-ros/, eigen is a system dependency. However, I can't find such package for groovy, except eigen-conversions, eigen-stl*, ecl-eigen*. I installed them, but the installation keeps complaining eigen isn't there. Apart from cross-compiling which I try to avoid, is there any solution ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/89786/eigen-in-groovy-for-ubuntu-12.04-armhf/) by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2013-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi skiesel,

Thanks for your response.

I installed libeigen3-dev. Now I used

sudo find /usr -name eigen*

and found that eigen is installed in /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen.
So apparently each installation goes different.

---

Originally posted by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) with karma: 72 on 2013-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skiesel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2807/skiesel/) on 2013-10-11**:
Well, glad you were able to resolve the issue.